# Crontab - combining times

Tags: linux, cron

I want to have my script run every 23'th around (so 11 PM) and between 7-19 every 2 hours. In directadmin I use this:

`23,7-19/2` however, in crontab it will be ran every minute. What syntax should I use? My complete line:

`* 23,7-19/2 * * * /usr/local/bin/php script.php`

Comment: [Administration panels are off topic](http://serverfault.com/help/on-topic). [Even the presence of an administration panel on a system,](http://meta.serverfault.com/q/6538/118258) because they [take over the systems in strange and non-standard ways, making it difficult or even impossible for actual system administrators to manage the servers normally](http://meta.serverfault.com/a/3924/118258), and tend to indicate low-quality questions from *users* with insufficient knowledge for this site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The key point with CRON is that it will run when ever the current time matches the pattern specified. So with all those *s, a lot of times will match.

I can't make sense of what exact times you are trying to describe though, so I can't give you the exact config that would work.

Comment: Thanks. I'm using `0 23,7-19/2 * * * /usr/local/bin/php script.php` now. I was using (as minutes) a '*', so every minute matched. Stupid me. Didn't saw the * at all...

Answer (score 2):

```
0 7,9,11,13,15,17,19 23 * * /usr/local/bin/php script.php
```

will run the script exactly at every second full hour on every 23th between 7h and 19h. But I am not sure anymore this is what you want to do.

Another interpretation would be that you want to run it between 7h and 19h and at 23h, but daily. Then change it to

```
0 7,9,11,13,15,17,19,23 * * * /usr/local/bin/php script.php
```

The six fields of the crontab are

```
min hour dayofmonth month dayofweek  command
```

Comment: Thanks. I'm using `0 23,7-19/2 * * * /usr/local/bin/php script.php` now. I was using (as minutes) a '*', so every minute matched. Stupid me. Thanks anyway!